# Speed difference cores in same NUMA node

Tags: c, linux, benchmarking, numa

I've noticed that running the Stream benchmark on different cores of the same NUMA node have noticeably different runtimes. What might explain this observation?

Comment: Besides the obvious that it uses different paths to the memory? Are you using classic Stream or a NUMA stream, such as https://github.com/larsbergstrom/NUMA-STREAM?

Comment: I believe I am using the NUMA stream. The main "anomaly" I'm seeing is that on each of the NUMA nodes, exactly half of them, with the lower core numbers, are noticeably faster than the other half. But within each half the runtimes are consistent.

Comment: Can you give some more info on the actual setup?